# How to get the text of all checked nodes in Treeview in delphi

Tags: delphi

this is the implementation for the treeview to have a check boxes in every nodes.

```
procedure TTreeView.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);  
begin
inherited;
    Params.Style := Params.Style or TVS_CHECKBOXES;
end;
```

now, i want to get all the text of all checked nodes in treeview and append it in memo

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, [Iterate recursively through nodes in a tree view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045263/iterate-recursively-through-nodes-in-a-tree-view), the focus is on checked and not on iterating, at least in older versions there is no direct access to checked.

Answer (score 1):

Sending a TVM_GETITEM message to the handle of a TreeItem will retrieve the needed state information in a TTVItem record defined in CommCtrl, if is called with the correct mask and ItemID.
The procedure `TreeView_GetItem` doing this can be found (and copied) in CommCtrl.

So you just need to iterate over your treeview items an check if the state is checked.

```
{type
  TTreeView = Class(ComCtrls.TTreeView)
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  End;}

uses CommCtrl;

Function TreeNodeChecked(n:TTreenode):Boolean;
Const
  TVIS_CHECKED = $2000;
var
   Item: TTVItem;
begin
   Item.mask := TVIF_STATE or TVIF_HANDLE;
   Item.hItem := n.ItemId;
   if Bool(SendMessage(n.Handle, TVM_GETITEM, 0, lParam(@Item))) then
       Result := (Item.State and TVIS_CHECKED) = TVIS_CHECKED
   else
       Result := false;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;
  for i := 0 to TV.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TreenodeChecked(TV.Items[i]) then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TV.Items[i].Text);
  end;
end;

{ TTreeView }

procedure TTreeView.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or TVS_CHECKBOXES;
end;
```